# find max(sum())

Tags: sql

```
create table dept
(
    did char(12) primary key,
    budget float,
    managerId int foreign key references emp
)
```

I write this query to find maximum sum

```
SELECT MAX(aa) AS max 
FROM 
    (SELECT SUM(budget) AS aa 
     FROM dept 
     GROUP BY managerId) dept
```

but I want to find the managerId that who can handle maximum budget.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: It seems do you use `sql server`, always preferable to tag your DB, when you asking database related questions

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 sum(budget), managerId 
from dept 
group by managerId 
order by sum(budget) desc
```

Comment: top 1 mean when budget order by desc order then select firsr row. am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Just pick these rows where `sum(budget)` is equal to `max`. use a subquery to calculate `max`

```
SELECT managerId 
FROM dept 
GROUP BY managerId 
HAVING sum( budget ) = (
         SELECT MAX(aa) as max 
         FROM (
            SELECT SUM(budget) AS aa FROM dept GROUP BY managerId
         ) dept
      )
```

Comment: this works but you need to delete the final 'dept'